# onSaveInstanceState causes the App to crash

Tags: android, android-fragments, activity-lifecycle

I have an App with one main activity, and this activity has 5 `actionTabs`, each `actionTab` contains a `fragment`, so I have 5 `fragments` as well.

The first `fragment` just displaying the word "hello".

In the second `fragment`, It just displays some `textviews` to indicate which callback of the activity's lifecycle is being called.

The third `fragment`, in its layout, it contains a `tablelayout` with 3 rows, each row has a `image`, `textview`and an `edittext`. And when access this `fragment` contained in this`tab` and when I rotate the device, the App does not crash.

The App crashes only when I access the fourth or the fifth `tab` and rotate the device which contains the following:

the fourth and the fifth `tab` have three `LinearLayout` and three `relative layout` respectively. The main `linearlayout` of the fourth `fragment` is oriented vertically, and the three nested `linearlayouts` are oriented horizontally, and each one of them contain `imageview`, `textview` and `edittext`.

The fifth `fragemnt` is almost the same as the fourth one, but instead of the `linearlayouts`, it has `relativlayout`.

**To Note**:

the second `fragment`has the method `onSavedInstance`, and when the App crashed when accessing the fourth or the fifth `fragment`, the `logcat` complains about the `onSavedInstance` and produce the below posted messages.

I want to know why the App crashes when I access either the fourth `fragment` or the fifth and rotate the device?

**LogCat**:

```
11-02 20:48:29.699: E/AndroidRuntime(22282): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

11-02 20:48:29.699: E/AndroidRuntime(22282): Process: com.example.viewpagerwithactiontabstest00, PID: 22282
11-02 20:48:29.699: E/AndroidRuntime(22282): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-02 20:48:29.699: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at com.example.viewpagerwithactiontabstest00.Aufgabe_2.onSaveInstanceState(Aufgabe_2.java:142)
11-02 20:48:29.699: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:1647)
11-02 20:48:29.699: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1610)

**onSavedInstance() methos**:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putString("TEXT", tv_00.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: It would appear that `tv00` is `null`.

Comment: but why it is null when i am in the fourth or the fifth fragment, and not null otherwise?

Comment: You are the only person on the planet who can answer that, as nobody else has any idea where you are initializing `tv00`.

Comment: tv_00 is initialised in the second fragment and it is declared in the second fragment layout

Comment: does tv_00 UI element have a unique value assigned to it in the xml file?

Comment: @harikris yes, it is assigned to an unique id

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment may be created, but not have had `onCreateView()` called yet. In that case, you would not have this widget yet in `onSaveInstanceState()`.

You might consider removing this `onSaveInstanceState()` entirely, using `android:freezesText` to arrange to ensure that this text view retains its text across a configuration change.

Comment: I tried the solution you offered but still the App crashes. i really do not know why only the 4th and th 5th fragments cause crashing

Comment: doesn't the system guarantee that the widget's state is persisted if the user assigns an `id` explicitly to the widget? If an `id` is attached, then is freezesText still a necessity?

Comment: @LetsAmrIt: "I tried the solution you offered but still the App crashes" -- it certainly cannot crash in `onSaveInstanceState()` if you do not have `onSaveInstanceState()`.

Comment: @harikris: "doesn't the system guarantee that the widget's state is persisted if the user assigns an id explicitly to the widget?" -- only user-mutable state by default. So the text of an `EditText` is saved to the `Bundle`, but not `TextView`. `android:freezesText` gives `TextView` the same save-the-content ability as `EditText` has. And, of course, I am assuming that there is an actual need to save this state here -- a `TextView` that is a static label can be left alone.